# Make [blue-ray] a synonym of [blu-ray] and [bluray]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[bluray](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bluray) is already a synonym of [blu-ray](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blu-ray), so why not make [blue-ray](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blue-ray) a synonym as well?

(Hope no-one creates [blueray](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/blueray)!)

Comment: Because nobody's ever used "blue-ray"? But yeah, I've created it.

Comment: @slhck: Actually 3 people did, but as you can probably see (if mods have access to a list of recent edits) before I created this topic I changed them all to blu-ray instead. Just thought I'd make things easier for you. :)

Comment: Oh, I see. We could've just merged them, so no need for editing in cases like this. But thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Cool, I'll keep that in mind for next time, since it'll save me work.